# Unable to add a Private npm module as dependency in angular2 app

Tags: angular, npm, angularjs-scope, angular2-forms, sinopia

I have set up a Pvt sinopia server in which I have published my apps (node Modules). Now, I have created a new local Angular2 Project in which I have installed these apps (modules) as dependencies. When I am trying to use these modules (by adding it as `import` in `app.module.ts`) 
I have added following to app.module.ts of my App

`import { FlashAppModule } from '@netapp/flash-advisor-ui'`;

`@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    FlashAppModule
  ],`

I get the following error.

The error is asking to convert @angular/ lambda functions to export function.

`ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a
reference to an exported function (position 194:50 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol NgModule in C:/sinopia/codeTest/node_modules/@netapp/flash
-advisor-ui/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol FlashAppModule in C:/sinopia/codeTest/node_modules/@netapp/flash-advisor-ui/src/app/ap
p.module.ts, resolving symbol FlashAppModule in C:/sinopia/codeTest/node_modules/@netapp/flash-advisor-ui/src/app/app.module.ts
    at positionalError (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25935:39)
    at simplifyInContext (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25772:31)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25786:17)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25282:64)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:126:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:101:26)
    at C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:117:27
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:116:10)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:52:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:78:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\sinopia\codeTest\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
webpack: Failed to compile.`

Comment: Please refrain from referring to codes using screenshots and more importantly refrain from using a link to refer to the screenshots. Include the code in your question to have a better chance of  getting an answer.

Comment: Yeah that screenshot is practically unreadable. Can you please post the error *text*?